# Cloud CDF and HTTPRedirect

Tags: gui-construction, wolfram-cloud, web-access

[Cross posted on community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1158296)

#### Question and requirements

Is it possible to `HTTPRedirect` from a *Cloud CDF* via e.g. `Button` action?

- I need an interactive cloud cdf around it.
- The action would not only redirect but evaluate arbitrary code prior to that.
- If it matters the target page does not need to be any page but an arbitrary `CloudObject` is enough.
- No, I don't want to hide old stuff and show new to the user, I really need to redirect.
- No, open in new tab does not count.

So it would work analogously to this form's submit button:

```
CloudDeploy[
    FormFunction[{"go on and submit"}
      , Module[{link}
          , link = CloudPut[RandomReal[], Permissions -> "Public"]
          ; HTTPRedirect[link]
        ] &
    ]
  , Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

#### Problems

Wasn't able to achieve that, here's why:

- `Form/ApiFunctions` where `HTTPRedirect` works well can't have interative CDFs embedded inside:

  ```
   CloudDeploy[
       FormFunction[
           { "this is ok"
           , ExportForm["this is not ok", "CloudCDFElement"]
           }
         , foo
       ]
     , Permissions -> "Public"
   ]
  ```

  > [image]
- and I can't trigger `HTTPRedirect` from cloud CDF, nothing happens:

  ```
      CloudDeploy[
        ExportForm[
          Button["Submit", Print[1]; HTTPRedirect["http://www.wolfram.com"]], 
          "CloudCDFElement"
        ], Permissions -> "Public"
       ]
  ```

  > [image]

Comment: Do you need both an actual and a hyperlink? You can obviously restyle a `Hyperlink` to look like a button. A `SystemOpen` call works too, except it's viewed as a popup. Is that okay?

Comment: @b3m2a1 nope, see above requirements :)

Comment: Ah. That's tougher. Well I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: So I took a break and came back to it and I'm not entirely sure WRI's made this possible yet. If you open a cloud notebook and make a hyperlink there, you can disable "Open in New Tab", but it doesn't actually do that. Since we don't have access to JS it's a lot harder. `EmbeddedHTML` seems to only let you work with iframes and I can't access the `StyleDefinitions` in the cloud so clearly they're baked in.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks for your time, yes I was afraid it may be impossible :-/ Cloud front end setup is way more obscure than desktop's so one never knows what is implemented/isn't/won't be etc.

Comment: Hopefully on community you can get one of the devs or something to give it a look. If that happens I'd definitely be interested in knowing what they say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are results of my experiments, so far works:

```
CloudDeploy[
    ExportForm[
        DynamicModule[{x = 1}, Column[{
            Slider@Dynamic@x,
            Dynamic@x,
            Button["Test redirect",
                Module[{link},
                    link = "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com";
                    Print @ EmbeddedHTML[ StringTemplate[
                       "<script>window.top.location.href =\"``\"</script>"
                    ]@link
                ]
            ]
        ]}]]
      , "CloudCDF"]
    , Permissions -> "Public"
  ]
```

`.top.` was added because `EmbeddedHTML` translates to an iframe and we don't want to redirect only that iframe itself. On the other hand your cloud object may be embedded in another page and `.top.` will redirect the whole page. You may need that or not, depends, at the end I'm using `.parent.` because I want to redirect only the CloudObject parent iFrame.

Comment: Wow I was doing that but just with the window.location.href. Good to see it's as simple as adding a top.

Comment: I found this Q/A very helpful - much thanks! BTW... CloudDeploy[ ExportForm[ Manipulate[ Column[{ a, Button["Test redirect", Module[ {link}, link = "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com"; Print@EmbeddedHTML[ StringTemplate[ "<script>window.top.location.href =\"``\"</script>"]@link]] ] }], {a, 0, 2}], "CloudCDF"], "testButtonV2", Permissions -> "Public"] My preference is Manipulate over DynamicModule but it's situational.

Comment: @Mitch I'm glad you find it useful. I converted your answer to a comment which it is. Hope you don't mind.